# Проверить наличие строки в черном списке

Tags: php

Написал скрипт, есть необходимость проверить пришедший на него post запрос на наличие домена в блек листе.
Т.е. создаю блек лист (к примеру, файл) с доменами:
ya.ru,google.com и т.д.

В момент обработки скрипта, нужно выполнить проверку пришедшего в post - url, если домен в блек листе - **вывести сообщение** и не исполнять скрипт ниже, если домена нет в блек листе - выполнить весь скрипт (глобальный блек лист).
Можно это осуществить?

Answer (score 0):

Полный ответ не дам - сам не шарю.

`script.php`

```
<?php
$blackList = array(
    'ya.ru',
    'google.com',
);
if (isset($_POST['url'])) {
    // Очень упрощенный вариант
    $domain = kak_to_tam_vstroennoy_php_funkciey_poluchit_domen($_POST['url']);
    if (in_array($domain, $blackList)) {
        echo 'Сайт в черном списке';
        return;
    }
}

echo 'Скрипт выполняется дальше';
```

Для самобытного варианта по усложненней переиничать $blackList в

```
$blackList = array(
    '#^https?\://ya\.ru#i',
    '#^https?\://google\.com#i'
);
```

и дальше вместо

```
if (in_array($domain, $blackList)) {
        echo 'Сайт в черном списке';
        return;
}
```

писать

```
$blackListed = false;
foreach($blackList as $item) {
    if (preg_match($item, $domain)) {
        $blackListed = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ($blackListed) {
        echo 'Сайт в черном списке';
        return;
}
```

Comment: `echo 'Скрипт выполняется дальше';` у меня там дальше кода много, как-то все в echo наверное нельзя помещать... подумаю как продолжить. Спасибо!

Comment: Извиняюсь за `echo` в конце. Это от балды вообще написал. Да, под `echo` я имел ввиду дальнейший код там в скрипте.

Comment: Так сделал https://i.gyazo.com/f4e93dbc1b3dc6cf87ccd4f0817d61fa.png работает! Чуть-чуть ваш код подправил. С noindex проблема...

Comment: ага. чито тама?

Comment: Допилить бы, чтобы учитывало http и https, у меня post как оказалось может с протоколом прийти, тогда скрипт пропускает блек домены...

Comment: Я могу подсказывать, только, не лазя в инет. Иначе какой толк подсказывать, если сам ищешь. Ну я так думаю. Ну и впадлу искать. Есть встроенная php функция для распарсивания ссылки на протокол, домен, путь и т.п. И есть вполне приемлемые и давно изобретенные методы для проверки ссылки в черном списке со всеми фичами.

Comment: Добавил в верхний коммент.

Comment: Лазить охота, я не знаю, что искать, искал php блек лист для доменов и не нашел.

Comment: Да уж, я как бы большеротик. Скажу и не скину ни одного примера :D о давно изобретенных методах. Ну вот, ладно - регулярки (`preg_match`)

Comment: Пока с blackListed разбираюсь, не увидел там http, соображаю   :)

Comment: Таем еще если адрес yandex.ru/all то он работает, т.е. блек лист работает только на имя домена, любая страница на этом домене проходит проверку   :(

Comment: Времени не было. Ладно, спроси кого-нибудь еще